# Hibernate Schema generation error

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jboss

I have some Entity '`Group`' as follows (getters and setters removed for readability)

```java
@Entity
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "Pflichtfeld")
    @Pattern(regexp = Validation.REG_NAMES, message = Validation.MSG_NAME)
    private String groupname;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "Pflichtfeld")
    private String groupDescription;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> members;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Rights> ownedRights;
}
```

When deploying to my JBoss I get following error:

> 15:08:53,464 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000388: **Unsuccessful:** create table Group (id bigint not null, groupDescription varchar(50) not null, groupname varchar(50) not null, primary key (id))
>   15:08:53,466 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-2) **Syntax error in SQL statement** "CREATE TABLE GROUP[*] (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, GROUPDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, GROUPNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID)) "; **expected "identifier"**; SQL statement:
>   create table Group (id bigint not null, groupDescription varchar(50) not null, groupname varchar(50) not null, primary key (id)) [42001-161]

My Persistence.xml looks as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/crmDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Why is the hibernate generated SQL Faulty? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

h2 database uses `GROUP` as a reserved word and as long as you use it you will have errors at table generations and at other queries generated by hibernate.

Either rename your model-class or use the class-level annotation `@Table` as documented in [the JBoss hibernate reference (esp. Section 2.1.1.1)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/)

Example usage:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="group_table")
public class Group {
```